# Creating ListView with check boxes...Android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am trying to create a listview that has check box beside each item. (i am following a code from the book android), but i can't get it to work, every time i run it, it crashes. since i am very new to this android staff, i have no clue what to do to get it to work, any help is appreciated.the code is below.
*i have created two layout files in names of list and list_item.
the code for the main activity:

```
public class ListDemoActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String[] listItems = {"exploring", "android","list", "activities"};
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lists);
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems));        

        //setContentView(R.layout.lists);
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        String[] cols = new String[]{People.NAME};
        int[] names = new int[]{R.id.row_tv};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,c,cols,names);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

the lists file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <ListView 
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit Selection"/>
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the list_item file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/row_chbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/row_tv" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i can't post the xml files :(

Comment: Did you enable android.permission.READ_CONTACTS in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the same book (Apress Android 2 Pro, source code at http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4529 - example /Ch4/Listing4-17)

I found when I copied / pasted it into an eclipse project, it didn't work for the simple reason that I hadn't set the package name at the top of the pasted source file.

Try putting:

package asdf.adsf;

...(with your actual package name ;-), at the top of the java file, maybe that will help. The problem was that it wasn't using the project-specific 'R' resource class.